# Automatic deployment of my django website after making changes

Tags: django, deployment

i have deployed my Django portfolio using nginx server.but now i want a feature in which i make changes to my Github repo and then it will get automatic deployed to my nginx server.
how can i do this?.
thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/) this will help you to pull code from the Github webhook and deploy it automatically, you just have to push code on Github.  You just have to install it on the server and set up everything.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cicd but recently it is requiered to validate  account with credit cart... if you dont have a card can use git hook for auto deployment

Comment: can you give a link to cicd docs or anything ? because a morrown like me can't find the stuff even if I use google.